# Flutter/Dart number handling ability

Tags: dart, flutter

I an kind of new in Flutter. I want to make a calculator with a large input. considering 30/40 digit each number. Can anybody help me with how I can do so? Like in android I used "BigDecimal" what is the alternative of that in Flutter?

Comment: Do you need fractional values? If not, Dart has a `BigInt` for large integers.

Comment: yes i need fractional values too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [decimal](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal) package.

```
// with double
print(0.2 + 0.1); // displays 0.30000000000000004

// with decimal
print(Decimal.parse('0.2') + Decimal.parse('0.1')); // displays 0.3
```

Comment: Decimals are built on [BigInt](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/BigInt-class.html) so there's no max value.