# Convert long double to string without scientific notation (Dart)

Tags: string, dart, double

I want to convert a long double to string without scientific notation in Dart, I thought just doing a .toString() would do the trick but it's not the case.

Here's my code:

```
void main() {  
  double num = 0.00000000196620214137477;
  String numToString = num.toString();
  
  print(num);
  print(numToString);
}
```

This is what it prints:

```
1.96620214137477e-9
1.96620214137477e-9
```

I want a string representation of the number as it was written when defined. So the printout I want after converting to string is:

```
0.00000000196620214137477
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the string representation of the number was `0.00000196620214137477e-3`, would you want to see that as the output too?

Comment: There is another way to do the same using [decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal/install).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you want directly with the Dart platform libraries, mainly because there is no way to do it in JavaScript.

You can use `num.toStringAsFixed(20)`, but that is limited to 20 digits, and your number needs 23.

One thing you could do is to manipulate the string directly:

```dart
String toExact(double value) {
  var sign = "";
  if (value < 0) {
    value = -value; 
    sign = "-";
  }
  var string = value.toString();
  var e = string.lastIndexOf('e');
  if (e < 0) return "$sign$string";
  assert(string.indexOf('.') == 1);
  var offset = int.parse(string.substring(e + (string.startsWith('-', e + 1) ? 1 : 2)));
  var digits = string.substring(0, 1) + string.substring(2, e);
  if (offset < 0) { 
    return "${sign}0.${"0" * ~offset}$digits";
  }
  if (offset > 0) {
    if (offset >= digits.length) return sign + digits.padRight(offset + 1, "0");
    return "$sign${digits.substring(0, offset + 1)}"
        ".${digits.substring(offset + 1)}";
  }
  return digits;
}
```

Do notice that you can't necessarily get the value *as written* because not all double values are exact. In this particular case, you seem to be be fine.

Comment: Sir could the formatting be achieved using [NumberFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) ?

Comment: Probably, yes. The `intl` package's `NumberFormat` seems to be doing roughly the same thing for fractions - convert the fraction to a string, then manipulate the string.

Comment: Sir there is another way to do the same using [decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal/install).

Comment: True. You'd have to go through the exponent notation, as `Decimal.parse(myDouble.toString())`, but then it should probably work.

Answer (score 5):

There is another simpler way to do this using [decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal/install). Recently came across [flutter-dart-number-handling-ability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158421/flutter-dart-number-handling-ability) question which pointed towards the package.

Example :

```
double originalNum = 0.00000000196620214137477;
Decimal convertedNum = Decimal.parse(originalNum.toString());
print('originalNum: $originalNum \n convertedNum: $convertedNum');
```

Output:

```
originalNum: 1.96620214137477e-9 
convertedNum: 0.00000000196620214137477
```

Answer (score 0):

It's anoyying that Flutter `toString`  method does not do the job If It's over 20 digits, I found much more easier solution:

```
String formatLargeNumber(double number) {
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat('###', 'en_US');
  return formatter.format(number);
}
```