# Convert exponential number to numeric Dart

Tags: dart

How can I convert exponential numbers to numeric?
For example, I have **4.903381641568837e-7** and want to convert it to **0.00000049034**...

Comment: Does this solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989638/convert-long-double-to-string-without-scientific-notation-dart

Comment: @Chilarai a bit not what I expected, but it works, thx

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) :

```
    import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

    void main() {
      double smallDouble = 0.0000000000000024353505535353555;

      final convertedDouble = Decimal.parse(smallDouble.toString());

      print("normal double :>> $smallDouble");
      print("Decimal :>> $convertedDouble");
    }
```

Output:

```
normal double :>> 2.4353505535353554e-15
Decimal :>> 0.0000000000000024353505535353554
```

Hope it could help.