# How to convert double into string with 2 significant digits?

Tags: flutter, dart, double

So i have small double values and i need to convert them into string in order to display in my app. But i care only about first two significant digits.
It should work like this:

```
convert(0.000000000003214324) = '0.0000000000032';
convert(0.000003415303) = '0.0000034';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert double to string, then check every index and take up to two nonzero (also `.`) strings. But the issue comes on **scientific notation for long double**.

You can check [Convert long double to string without scientific notation (Dart)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62989638/10157127)

We need to find exact String value in this case. I'm taking help from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62990084/10157127)

```dart
String convert(String number) {
  String result = '';

  int maxNonZeroDigit = 2;

  for (int i = 0; maxNonZeroDigit > 0 && i < number.length; i++) {
    result += (number[i]);
    if (number[i] != '0' && number[i] != '.') {
      maxNonZeroDigit -= 1;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

String toExact(double value) {
  var sign = "";
  if (value < 0) {
    value = -value;
    sign = "-";
  }
  var string = value.toString();
  var e = string.lastIndexOf('e');
  if (e < 0) return "$sign$string";
  assert(string.indexOf('.') == 1);
  var offset =
      int.parse(string.substring(e + (string.startsWith('-', e + 1) ? 1 : 2)));
  var digits = string.substring(0, 1) + string.substring(2, e);
  if (offset < 0) {
    return "${sign}0.${"0" * ~offset}$digits";
  }
  if (offset > 0) {
    if (offset >= digits.length) return sign + digits.padRight(offset + 1, "0");
    return "$sign${digits.substring(0, offset + 1)}"
        ".${digits.substring(offset + 1)}";
  }
  return digits;
}


void main() {
  final num1 = 0.000000000003214324;
  final num2 = 0.000003415303;

  final v1 = convert(toExact(num1));

  final v2 = convert(toExact(num2));
  print("num 1 $v1 num2 $v2");
}
```

Run on  [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d5ccb4a9e5ca836a7d3c1e77b0801da9)

Comment: There is an error if the number has only one digit(0,00000000001).
So you need to replace
`var digits = string.substring(0, 1) + string.substring(2, e);`
into
`final digits = string.substring(0, e).replaceAll('.', '');`