# Convert a exponential number to number in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert this number `9.20E+11` into "919989000000" ? From exponential to number in flutter/dart? "919989000000" this represents the numerical form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert long double to string without scientific notation (Dart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989638/convert-long-double-to-string-without-scientific-notation-dart)

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana no

Comment: dart number literals can be written this way, so you can simply write `double x = 9.20E+11;`. If you are getting this number as a string, you can also parse it with `double x = double.parse('9.20E+11');`.

Comment: @mmcdon20 `double.parse`  prints  `920000000000`. This is not the required output

Comment: The notation just means to move the decimal point `11` places to the right starting with `9.20`. Whatever process you did to get `9.20E+11` from `919989000000` in the first place was probably rounded to the nearest hundredth place.

Comment: If you want to get `919989000000`, you would have to have `9.19989E+11` as the number to start with.

Answer (score 1):

In Dart you can do it with math library. [Documentatiin](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-math/dart-math-library.html)

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  num n = 9.20E+0;
  double e = exp(n);
  print(e); // 9897.129058743909
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want output in numbers (double) you can **import 'dart:math';** Library and write:

```
 num n = 9.20E+0;
 double e = exp(n);
 print(e);
```

Else if you want to display in String you can write directly by toString() method.

```
double num = 9.20E+11;
String str= num.toString();
print(str);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).